# What is `inputProcRefCon` in the `AURenderCallbackStruct`?

Tags: ios, core-audio

In playing a tone (e.g., [here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html)), we have to tell the machine what function will fill the IO buffer:

```
// Set our tone rendering function on the unit
AURenderCallbackStruct input;
input.inputProc = RenderTone;
input.inputProcRefCon = self;
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(toneUnit, 
    kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Input,
    0, 
    &input, 
    sizeof(input));
```

It's clear that `inputProc` is the procedure from which to take input for the audiounit. But what is `inputProcRefCon` exactly? Would there ever be a case where it **cannot** be set to `self`?

Answer (score 8):

The refCon is a void (untyped) pointer to arbitrary data, in your example to the C struct backing the calling object.  If the inputProc callback function doesn't need any extra parameters (instance variables) from the calling object passed, then you don't need to pass it self, or you can point refCon at some other data (a different C struct or object).  But most callbacks do need some parameters.

It's a C void pointer because the API is for real-time code that predates newer Objective C idioms.

Comment: Not only _predates_, but use of Objective-C messages is __discouraged__ in an input render callback function in the sample code [("In addition, it's usually best to avoid sending Objective-C messages in a render callback.")](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/mixerhost/listings/Classes_MixerHostAudio_m.html)

Comment: Yes ObjC messages shouldn't be used in an input render callback for performance issues. The CPU allows a very short time to its thread (around 29ms) and calling ObjC methods (which send ObjcC message) take more time! You can read the full explanation with the [great article of Michael Tyson](http://atastypixel.com/blog/four-common-mistakes-in-audio-development/)

Answer (score 1):

It's short for "input procedure's reference context". So, to elaborate on @hotpaw2's answer, it's a reference to arbitrary data that can be used in an audio unit's render callback.

For example, if your Audio Unit is supposed to process incoming audio, then `inputProc` must point to the buffer containing the samples you need it to process.

```c
float **_myBuffer; // initialise this properly!

AURenderCallbackStruct callback = {0};
callback.inputProc = MyAudioUnitEffectCallback;
callback.inputProcRefCon = _myBuffer;
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(AURenderCallbackStruct);
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_myAudioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &callback, propertySize);
assert(status == noErr);

// then elsewhere in the file:

OSStatus MyAudioUnitEffectCallback(void *                            inRefCon,
                                   AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *      ioActionFlags,
                                   const AudioTimeStamp *            inTimeStamp,
                                   UInt32                            inBusNumber,
                                   UInt32                            inNumberFrames,
                                   AudioBufferList * __nullable      ioData) {

    // inputBuffer is going to be _myBuffer
    float ** inputBuffer = static_cast<float **>(inRefCon);
    // process the samples inside it and then place them into ioData
```